# WordPress - 'author' argument is not working in custom post query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this weird problem. I am writing a query to get posts by a specific author using either author's id or username. The query works fine if I won't use 'author' argument and shows resutls. But as soon as I put in author argument, the query shows no result. Can someone help me debugging the issue? I have tried every possible query I could think of. Like:

```
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post_status' => 'draft,publish');
```

**Query 1:**

```
    query_posts($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<h1>';
        the_title();
        echo '</h1>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
```

**Query 2:**

```
    $listmycampaign = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($listmycampaign->have_posts()) {

        while($listmycampaign->have_posts()){

            $listmycampaign->the_post();

            echo '<h1>'.the_title().'</h1>';    


        };  

    }
```

**Query 3:**

```
    $current_author = get_query_var('author');
    $author_posts=  get_posts( 'author='.$user->id.'&posts_per_page=-1' );
    if($author_posts){
    echo "Mijn dagboek berichten";
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($author_posts as $author_post)  {
     echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($author_post->ID).'">'.$author_post->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
```

All of the queries work if I won't use/give author argument. What could be wrong?
I have tried disabling all plugins, I have tried different author IDs, usernames, but these won't work even for "admin" as the author username.

**Update 1:**
Ok so it appears that it is a theme problem. I switched to default "twenty fifteen" theme and now, all of the queries started to work. Even with author argument. How can I track down the issue?

Comment: where are you running this

Comment: I have used it in a custom page template and also in index page. I never works.

Comment: Do you have debug set to true, what errors are you seeing

Comment: have tried to switch to a bundled theme, I see you already disabled all plugins

Comment: Yes. I just did that and the queries are working fine now even with the author argument. So it is a theme problem. How can I track and tackle?

Comment: Set `'suppress_filters' => true` in your `WP_Query` arguments, if this solves the issue, you have a `posts_where` filter that is bad, if it does not, look for `pre_get_posts` in your theme. Lastly, something in your theme on that page uses `query_posts` (*which you shoud never ever use) or a bad query that is not resetted

Comment: I tried "echo $listmycampaign -> request" to know about the query. I can see the issue. When I put in the "author" argument, the post_type changes from "product" to "download". Here is the response. SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_author IN (2) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'download' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: Try what I said above. It really looks like a bad filter

Comment: Hey man. You were absolutely correct. In the theme I was using, they had defined an action for author archive using 'pre_get_posts'. That action was changing the post_type to download whenever I use author argument in my custom query. As soon as I removed that filter and the query started working good. Thank you man. This would not have been possible without you :-)

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Enjoy ;-)